# Android - Need Calculator to pop up when editing a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, calculator

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a simple calculator pop up when I start to edit a EditText.  Once I add the numbers together I want the result to go to the EditText i'm working on.  I've seen this in other app's.  Is this something that needs to be write from scratch or is there a better way to accomplish it?

Thanks for all the help.  This site is the best!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this widget before, but I imagine it would be pretty fun to write.

I think it would be pretty easy to write as a sort of [custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

Comment: This is the app with the calculator that I really like. http://market.android.com/details?id=com.handyapps.percentcalc